# Script out schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a schema in SQL Server database. There are also bunch of other scripts in the database. Can I script out an existing schema? I mean, suppose we have a table, we can 
script out a `CREATE TABLE` script? Can we script out a Create Schema.

Thanking You Guys in Anticipation,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right click on the database node in SSMS, you can script the whole schema.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx) how-to on MSDN.

> ### Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard
>
> Use the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard to create a Transact-SQL
>   script for many objects. The wizard generates a script of all the
>   objects in a database, or a subset of the objects that you select. The
>   wizard has many options for your scripts, such as whether to include
>   permissions, collation, constraints, and so on. For more information,
>   see Generate Scripts Wizard F1 Help.
>
> ### To open the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, expand Databases, right-click a database, point
>      to Tasks, and then click Generate Scripts. Follow the steps in the
>      wizard to script the database objects.
> 2. On the Choose Objects page, select the objects to be included in the
>      script. For more information, see Generate Scripts Wizard (Choose
>      Objects Page).
> 3. On the Set Scripting Options page, select Save scripts to a specific
>      location. To specify advanced scripting options, select the Advanced
>      button in the Save scripts to a specific location section. a.Select the location for the generated script: to a file, a Database
>      Engine Query Editor window, or the Clipboard. b. For more information, see Generate Scripts Wizard (Set Scripting
>      Options Page).
> 4. On the Summary page, review your selections. Click Previous to
>      change your selections. Click Next to generate a script of the
>      objects you selected. For more information, see Generate Scripts
>      Wizard (Summary Page).
> 5. On the Save or Publish Scripts page, monitor the progress of the
>      script generation. For more information, see Generate Scripts Wizard
>      (Save or Publish Scripts Page)

Answer (score 7):

I wrote an open source command line utility named [SchemaZen](https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen#schemazen---script-and-create-sql-server-objects-quickly) that does this. It's much faster than scripting from management studio and it's output is more version control friendly. It supports scripting both schema and data.

To generate scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe script --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Then to recreate the database from scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe create --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Comment: One problem with this, is that the script does not include everything, like permissions, naming of "unnamed"  keys and contstraints. So if you use this, let us say to generate a script from a production server to compare it with a dev server or a database project, you get a bunch of differences. If your tool that it would be really useful.

Comment: @vzczc Thanks for the feedback. Please submit feature requests here https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen/issues/new