# How can i get script for existing database?

Tags: sql-server

My problem is that i need to provide script for creating my database to my teacher. I have created it but i didnt save anything. May i somehoves get a script for creating database and all tables which are in it, if i have this base on my sql server?

[base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3rEz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script out schema in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277495/script-out-schema-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

- a1. Right-click on the Database you want to export
- a2. Select "Tasks / Generate Scripts..."

This will open the "Generate and Publish Scripts" wizard.

On the "Choose Objects" tab:

- b1. Pick all your database tables
- b2. Select "Single File"
- b3. Click Advanced Options and select "Table/View Options" / "Script Indexes"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your IDE and DB, but it's about the similar actions for all cases. For example:

1. **SSMS** - Object Explorer -> Databases -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Script all objects in the selected database -> Next
2. **DataGrip** - right click on DB -> SQL scripts -> Generate DDL...

In any case, this can be done using any IDE, and you can select parameters in the settings (create only a structure or additionally add data from tables to the script, etc.)